# Is this program to get the mininmum value in a stack of O(1) complexity?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have implemented push pop and get minimum in O(1) complexity. I have seen many solutions in C++. This is an implementation in C itself. Is the following program correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int stack[15],aux[15];
int top=-1,count=-1,aux_count=-1,temp_aux=-1;
void push_auxilary(int ele)
{
aux[++aux_count] = ele;
}
void push_stack(int ele)
{
    stack[++top]=ele;
}
void push(int ele)
{
    if(top < 0 && aux_count < 0)
    {
        push_auxilary(ele);
        push_stack(ele);
    }
    else
        {
            if(ele > aux[aux_count])
            {
                push_auxilary(aux[aux_count]);
                push_stack(ele);
            }
            else
            {
                push_stack(ele);
                push_auxilary(ele);
            }
        }
}
int pop_stack()
{
    return stack[top--];
}
int pop_auxilary()
{
    return aux[aux_count--];
}
int pop()
{
    int a = pop_stack();
    pop_auxilary();
    return a;
}
void display()
{
    for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
        /* code */
    }
}
int get_min()
{
    return aux[aux_count];
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    push(5);
    push(9);
    push(1);
    push(6);
    push(1);
    push(54);
    push(34);
    push(9);
    push(3);
    push(4);
    push(7);
    push(12);
    push(02);
    printf("the %d\n",get_min() );
    for (i = aux_count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",aux[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fancy indentation you have there, really pleases the eye.

Comment: Looks like O(1) time to me, aside from the printing functions. No loops or recursion implies constant time.

Comment: @adam ya i thought the same thing. my doubt is the no of comparisons i make also affect the complexity right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, comparisons don't affect the time complexity. Think of time complexity as the "number of operations". Your comparisons run in O(2) or O(4) or O(5) or whatever, and your display loop runs in O(2n). Time complexity removes the leading constant and replaces it with `1`, since in the long run, the number of single operations don't really matter. Because your program only has single operations, and no loops, it runs in constant time.

Comment: Any *program* executing at any specific point in time is always going to be O(1). In this case the program is processing N values, and the N is constant, meaning that any time you run this program it's going to consume the same number of operations as last time. In this regard, it's O(1). On the other hand, Big-O operation is never applied to *programs*. And as such, who cares. A program that does the same every time, why not just output a constant list of values instead of going through all the rigamarole of evaluating what values to output? The interesting part is the *algorithm* used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it gets the job done in O(1) indeed. Algorithmic-ally correct, but terrible from code reusage point of view.

Comment: the first stack is main one and the additional one is to track the minimum one in o(1) complexity rather than o(n) complexity.  you can never find the minimum in o(1) without an additional stack data-structure.